# DbSet include extension method looping

Tags: linq, entity-framework-5, linq-to-objects, c#-5.0

I've added the following extension method

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Provides a statically typed interface for db includes
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    /// <param name="set">The set.</param>
    /// <param name="includes">The includes.</param>
    /// <returns>DbSet&lt;T&gt;.</returns>
    public static DbSet<T> Include<T>(this DbSet<T> set, params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includes) where T : class
    {
        if (includes != null)
        {
            foreach (var expression in includes)
            {
                set.Include(expression);
            }
        }
        return set;
    }
```

This is based on the repository code I found here

https://github.com/carbonrobot/FullStackEF/tree/master/src

However, when I utilise this with the following

```
    public ServiceResponse<Town> Get(int id)
    {
        Func<Patient> func = delegate
        {
            using (var context = _contextFactory())
            {
                return context.Get<Town>(id, x => x.County);
            }
        };
        return this.Execute(func);
    }
```

Where the town class contains a County entity.

I am getting a infinite loop as its calling the extension method rather than the base include?

Any ideas what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There a several mistakes in that method.

The [`DbExtensions.Include`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg671236(v=vs.103).aspx) method has the following signature:

```
public static IQueryable<T> Include<T, TProperty>(
    this IQueryable<T> source,
    Expression<Func<T, TProperty>> path
)
where T : class
```

As you can see, it receives `IQueryable<T>` and returns another `IQueryable<T>` which has to be assigned to a variable and returned instead of the original in order to has effect, which the code is not doing.

Also, since the method calls `Include` on the `set` variable of type `DbSet<T>` which is more concrete than the `IQueryable<T>`, and the argument matches the signature of the custom method, the compiler simply calls the same method, hence the `StackOverflowException`.

With that being said, here is the correct custom method signature and implementation:

```
public static IQueryable<T> Include<T>(this DbSet<T> set, params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includes)
    where T : class
{
    var result = set.AsQueryable();
    if (includes != null)
    {
        foreach (var expression in includes)
        {
            result = result.Include(expression);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the detailed explaination. One question though as the repo uses the DbSet returned to chain the methods. i.e. .include(includes).find(id) As the extension method is return IQueryable<T> (as opposed to DbSet<T> I lose the ability to chain? any ideas with this?

Comment: Hmm, this sounds unresolvable, but `Include` doesn't work with `Find` anyway, so I guess it makes no sense to be chained with `Find`. The regular LINQ chains should work though. The rationale is that the result of the `Include` is no more `DbSet`

Comment: Ok great. So basically you'd recommend simply .include(includes).select(x => x.Id == id); (in respect to the find example). To filter down the queryable results?

Comment: Something like that - to be precise - `.Include(includes).FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);`